# How can I make the bottom of my div have a peak shape?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my div have this form:

[image]

I only get this result with the code I am using:

```css
div {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 34rem;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Thanks for you help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only about coloration you don't need to use `clip-path`. You can easily achieve this with multiple background and have a better support:

```css
div.box {
  height: 300px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) top/100% 70%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,blue 49.8%,transparent 50%) bottom right/50% 30%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue 49.8%,transparent 50%) bottom left/50.2% 30%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

In case you need the black border you can adjust like below:

```css
div.box {
  height: 300px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) top/100% 70%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,blue calc(50% - 5px),#000 calc(50% - 5px),#000 49.8%,transparent 50%) bottom right -20px/calc(50% + 20px) 30%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue calc(50% - 5px),#000 calc(50% - 5px),#000 49.8%,transparent 50%) bottom left  -20px/calc(50% + 21px) 30%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 34rem;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This link is helpful https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/